# How do I Filter react data using a button not the search input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filtering

I am trying to filter products in React based on the category which is stored in NodeJs. The search using input is working as it should, but when I try to filter them using a button it only filters the first button (ex: Tart), and once I click on another button all the products disappear and nothing shows until I refresh the page. I have been trying for two days and I can't figure it out.

- Fetch data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAnwk.png)
- Input filter and button filter [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2NJt.png)
- categories [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHNyd.png)
- products [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3O73.png)

Comment: Sorry for the images, its my first time posting and I can't add my code keeps giving me error.

Comment: [Please post code/etc as formatted text rather than links to pictures of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There should be no issue adding the necessary code to your question.

Comment: Please do not use code image copy/past your code with a good formatting for a better lisibility

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that you are using `filteredProducts` instead of using the state that you have assigned the value using `setProduct` i.e., product.

You should do `product.map(x)=>{...}` instead.

And next time you post a question, please ensure that you are giving your code in text form instead of images as it's not really easy to read it otherwise.